Oracle APEX: allow additional values in the select list
I have a select list that has a is set to Static LOV with two values 'YES' and 'NO' but I want to allow the user to add additional values to it by typing them in or be setting the select list to a value in code. I have Display Extra Values selected but that still does not work. If the field is set to a value not in the static list, nothing gets selected. But if I check session state, P1_RESPONSE is set to the value I set it to in code. What can I do to allow an extra value to be entered?

A page item of type "select list" does not support that functionality. The "show additional values" attribute will display a value even if it is not available in the list definition.
Available alternatives are:

Popup LOV. This supports additional values out of the box: check the "Manual Entry" attribute



Use a select list combined with a dynamic action to control an additional page item. When a user selects value "other", the additional page item is shown allowing to enter the user whatever he wants.

